# Drupal 7: Multiple View Mode in Views Search Filter

Tags: views, search, entities

I have a Content Type with 2 Custom View Modes.
Is there a way to combine View Modes into one search filter in Views?

What I'm trying to do is create a search function using Views Filter. 
If the search term exists in the Teaser View Mode, only that View Mode will be used in search result, and if the search term exists in the Second View Mode, the same thing happens (only that View Mode will be used in the search result).

How can I accomplish something like this?

**Edit:**
Here is an example. I have a Movie listing. When I would like to search the Movie Title, the result would only be the Movie with its images (View Mode 1). When I search for Casts (Names), only the name listing would show (View Mode 2). But all the data are in the same Content Type.

Comment: Do you mean 2 views will be displayed based on the search result. like if there is data exist show views1 else check with views2 for the same ?

Comment: @Jeet So how do I accomplish that one you described? Thanks

Comment: Nevermind. I found an answer: https://drupal.org/node/1547774
It may not be exactly what I'm looking for but it's good enough.